# why laravel is not entering into public folder which contains index.php

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

i have a `problem`  my program is not entering into public folder.

**what i have done is:**

1. changed `server.php` to `index.php`
2. moved `css,js,images` to `root` folder but `copied` .htaccess to `root` folder

now my code enters into index.php in **root**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}


echo __DIR__.'/public/index.php'; die;  <-- for debuggig when i remove 500 error

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

**the above code before die gives** `/home/ebsprint/public_html/enigma-crm/public/index.php`

**now the real problem (folder public - files)**

```
public 
        -  .htaccess
        -  index.php
```

folder **public** inside `index.php`

```
<?php

      echo 'here'; die;
```

**gives 500 error**

**Question**: on local environment it is working fine, but on hosting, **root** `index.php` call is not going to  **public/index.php**

Comment: nginx or apache?

Comment: which programmmmmm

Comment: @Nikita, it is apche

Answer (score 0):

Just add .htaccess code and you don't require to change Laravel directory structure.
**use this code under the root directory**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```